# Parsing data to a serialized array  produces scalar value warnings and fatal string offset

Tags: php, xml, arrays, serialization

I am trying to parse data into a serialized array but can't figure it out and it errors out. What I am trying to do is utilize update_post_meta to fill in the serialized array with values that will be parsed to it.

example output of the array:

```
get_post_meta('840', '_eshop_product',true ); 


(
[sku] => 1234567885 
[products] => 
Array 
( 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [option] => Retail 
        [price] => 3.99 
        [tax] => 1 
        [saleprice] =>
     )
 ) 
[description] => Astonishing X-men 
[shiprate] => A 
[featured] => Yes 
[sale] => yes 
[cart_radio] => 0 
[optset] => 
)
```

All i can find for resources is examples of get_post_meta and I'm trying to utilize update_post_meta to parse new data into these fields. Here's the code:

```
$meta2 = update_post_meta($post_id, '_eshop_product', true);
$meta3 = update_post_meta;
$meta3($post_id, '_eshop_stock', true); //works

$meta2['sku']=htmlspecialchars($_POST['eshop_sku']); //this is line 90
if($meta2['sku']=''){update_post_meta($meta2['_sku'], "{$id}");} //this is line 91

$numoptions=$eshopoptions['options_num'];
for($i=1;$i<=$numoptions;$i++)
{
    $meta2['products'][$i]['option']=htmlspecialchars($_POST['eshop_option_'.$i]); //this is line 96
    if($_POST['eshop_price_'.$i]='0'){update_post_meta($meta2($_POST['eshop_price_'.$i]), "{pricing_high}");}

    if($_POST['eshop_tax_'.$i]='No'){update_post_meta($meta2($_POST['eshop_tax_'.$i]), 'band 1');} //this is line 99
}

$meta2['description']=htmlspecialchars($_POST['eshop_product_description']);
if($meta2['description']==''){update_post_meta($meta2['description'], 'singles');}

$meta2['shiprate']=$_POST['eshop_shipping_rate'];
if($meta2['shiprate']='F'){update_post_data($meta2['_Shipping Rate'], 'A');}

if($_POST['eshop_sale_product']=='No'){update_post_meta( $id, '_eshop_sale', 'yes');}
```

And these are the errors that I get:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/mtgpage.php on line 90

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/mtgpage.php on line 91

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/mtgpage.php on line 96

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/mtgpage.php on line 99
```

When I edit the product also in wordpress where the custom data would be located under the editor - there is an error and the custom fields will not display:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/eshop/eshop-product-entry.php on line 44
```

Comment: string offset, scalar value and function not a string - updated code with more details - thx for the interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors there. The first 3 errors are regarding the function `update_post_meta()` which is not returning an array. So `$meta2` is not an array and you cannot treat it like that. So check that function and be sure it is returning an array.

Every if of your script, will return true.
For example `if($meta2['shiprate']='F')` is always true because you are assigning `$meta2['shiprate']` = to a string and the evaluated test is `if ('F')` which is true. You might be wanting to test the value of `$meta2['shiprate']` then you have to use `==` like this: `if($meta2['shiprate']=='F')`.

For the last error, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to active here: `$meta2($_POST['eshop_tax_'.$i])`, but it is not a valid use of variable of variable attached to a string function name. You probably want to do `$meta2[$_POST['eshop_tax_'.$i]]`.